# JUDDI not valid service error

Tags: java, maven, juddi

i am using JUDDI libraries to register my service at JUDDI. When i execute the below code, i got the error

{urn:uddi-org:v3_service}UDDI_Security_Port is not a valid service. Valid services are: {urn:uddi-org:v3_service}UDDISecurityService

Code:

```
try {
         String clazz = UDDIClientContainer.getUDDIClerkManager(null).
         getClientConfig().getUDDINode("default").getProxyTransport();
         Class<?> transportClass = ClassUtil.forName(clazz, Transport.class);

         if (transportClass!=null) {

            transport = (Transport) transportClass.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance("default");  
            System.out.println("Second satement");
                 security = transport.getUDDISecurityService();
          juddiApi = transport.getJUDDIApiService();
          publish = transport.getUDDIPublishService();
                 inquiry = transport.getUDDIInquiryService();
         }   

     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Below are the maven dependencies, i am using for JUDDI.

        org.apache.juddi
        juddi-client
        3.0.4
      
 
    org.apache.juddi
    juddi-core
    3.1.5

Below is my uddi.xml file

```
<uddi>
    <reloadDelay>5000</reloadDelay>
    <manager name="example-manager">
        <nodes>
            <node>
                <name>default</name>
                <description>Main jUDDI node</description>  
                <properties>
                    <property name="serverName"  value="localhost"/>
                    <property name="serverPort"  value="8080"/>
                    <property name="keyDomain"   value="juddi.apache.org"/>
                    <property name="department"  value="businesses" />
                </properties>
                <proxyTransport>
                    org.apache.juddi.v3.client.transport.JAXWSTransport
                </proxyTransport>

    <custodyTransferUrl>
        http://${serverName}:${serverPort}/juddiv3/services/custody-transfer?wsdl
    </custodyTransferUrl>
    <inquiryUrl>
        http://${serverName}:${serverPort}/juddiv3/services/inquiry?wsdl
    </inquiryUrl>
    <publishUrl>
        http://${serverName}:${serverPort}/juddiv3/services/publish?wsdl
    </publishUrl>
    <securityUrl>
        http://${serverName}:${serverPort}/juddiv3/services/security?wsdl
    </securityUrl>
    <subscriptionUrl>
        http://${serverName}:${serverPort}/juddiv3/services/subscription?wsdl
    </subscriptionUrl>
    <subscriptionListenerUrl>
        http://${serverName}:${serverPort}/juddiv3/services/subscription-listener?wsdl
    </subscriptionListenerUrl>
    <juddiApiUrl>
        http://${serverName}:${serverPort}/juddiv3/services/juddi-api?wsdl
    </juddiApiUrl>

            </node>
        </nodes>
    </manager>
</uddi>
```

I have installed JUDDI portal on my localhost.

Answer (score 0):

First problem your dependencies are out of whack. 
 org.apache.juddi juddi-client 3.1.5 or the latest one available

Second problem is that you're missing a dependency
 org.apache.juddi uddi-ws 3.1.5 or the latest one available

juddi-core is only for hosting the web services and accessing the database.

That should fix it.

The ASF SVN has a bunch of examples, including a POM that should always be up to date.
Here's for the latest dev trunk
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/juddi/trunk/juddi-examples/hello-world/pom.xml

Here's one for 3.1.5
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/juddi/tags/juddi-3.1.5/juddi-examples/hello-world/pom.xml